# Connect 4 diagonal logic via matrix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, regex

I'm wanting to add a horizontal check for a winning move in my connect 4 game - However I'm completely flumoxed with how to proceed.

There are already working checks for horizontal and vertical.

You can see that we are checking with a regex test against a stringified version of the array matrix.

A winning **vertical** array looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Array and joined array passed to the test function:
[image]

A winning **horiontal** array looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Array and joined array passed to the horizontal test function:

[image]

A winning **diagonal** array looks like this:

[image]
[image]

```
const testWin = (arr: number[]): boolean => /1{4}|2{4}/.test(arr.join(""));

const usePlayPiece = () => {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(boardState);
  const [player, setPlayerTurn] = useState(playerState);
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(gameOverState);

  return (col: number) => {
    // Play piece (non mutating)
    const newBoard = board.map((column, i) => (i === col) ? [...column, player] : column);
    const row = newBoard[col].length - 1;

    if (
      testWin(newBoard[col]) // Did win vertically
      || testWin(newBoard.map((col) => col[row] || 0)) // Did win horizontally
      // || testWin() // Did win diagonally
    ) {
      setGameOver(true);
    } else {
      // Keep playing
    }

    setBoard(newBoard);
  };
};
```

Comment: Are you operating on strings with regex for performance reasons or do you just want to validate a winning streak regardless of regex use?

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin I'm happy to adapt to whichever route is easiest/best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could temporarily pad your columns with zeroes so they are equally sized (typically to length 6). Then turn that 2D array to a string, where the columns are separated with an extra character, and then use a one-for-all regular expression on it:

```
const testWin = (arr: number[][]): boolean =>  => 
    /([12])(\1{3}|(.{5}\1){3}|(.{6}\1){3}|(.{7}\1){3})/.test(
        arr.map(col => col.join("").padEnd(6, "0")).join(",")
    );
```

And just have one call where you pass the complete board as argument:

```
if (testWin(newBoard)) {
    // game over...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in with the string version of your array, you need to test the full matrix through so you will need to pad out numbers after the last entry in all columns. This will allow you to test for a consistent pattern.

Using a 6 * 7 array you would end up with 6 numbers between each number you are testing for. The regex then will look like

1\d{6}1\d{6}1\d{6}1|2\d{6}2\d{6}2\d{6}2

For the opposite direction you will swap the {6} for {4}.

This can be simplified to 1(\d{6}1){3}|2(\d{6}2){3} and 1(\d{4}1){3}|2(\d{4}2){3}

Answer (score 0):

Apart from operating on strings (which I think might be faster for very large matrices), the problem can be generalized on m x n matrices:

```
function genMtrx (n,m, probEmp = 0.8){
    return Array.from({length:n}).map(d =>
        Array.from({length:m}).map(d => 
            Math.random() < probEmp ? 0 : Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2
        )    
    )
}
```

Normally there are 8 directions you can go (l,r,t,b,tr,tl,bl,br), but since you are testing every cell until you hit a winning condition, you would need 4 of the directions like the others posted here:

```
const dirs = {
    right: (i,j) => [i+1, j],
    top: (i,j) => [i, j+1],
    topleft: (i,j) => [i-1,j+1],
    topright: (i,j) => [i+1,j+1]
}
```

Then based on these dirs, you can generalize a winning condition:

```
function isWinning(mtrx, nr = 1){
    let streak = 0,
        nCol = mtrx.length,
        nRow = mtrx[0].length,
        dirKeys = Object.keys(dirs),
        dirKeysL = dirKeys.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < nCol; ++i){
        for (let j = 0; j < nRow; ++j) {
            for (let k = 0; k < dirKeysL; ++k) {
                let dir = dirs[dirKeys[k]],
                    [nI, nJ] = dir(i,j),
                    cell = mtrx[nI]?.[nJ];
                while (cell && cell === nr) {
                    if(++streak === 4) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    [nI, nJ] = dir(nI, nJ);
                    cell = mtrx[nI]?.[nJ];
                }
                streak = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The function default tests for opponent1, but if you pass 2, it will test that one instead. Then you can do (for opponent 2):

```
isWinning(genMtrx(100,100,0.9),2)
```

I am sure the algorithm can be optimized much further. I also think if the matrix is large enough, it is better to pick random cells or do a 2D binary search. In that case you will have to put back the omitted 4 directions into the `dirs` object.